# How to enable/disable mod_deflate based on a cookie?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-deflate, cookie, http-cookie

I would like to enable mod_deflate based on the presence and value of a certain cookie.

I know it’s possible to do [cookie manipulation and tests with mod_rewrite](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-fresh.html#modrewrite2), but I’m not sure how to do that kind of stuff with mod_deflate.

Is this possible at all? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SetEnvIf HTTP_COOKIE "NODEF" no-gzip dont-vary
```